# Str replace method happening inplace

Tags: python, string, qt, replace, str-replace

I have a Python string which I want to `\include` in a latex file. However, my string has an underscore character (`_`), which needs to be converted into `\_` (this is latex representation for _) before included.

If I do:

```
self.name = self.laser_comboBox.currentText() #Get name from a qt widget
latex_name = self.name.replace("_", r"\_") #Replacing _ for \_
print self.name
print latex_name
```

I'll get:

```
XXXXXX-YY\_SN2017060009
XXXXXX-YY\_SN2017060009
```

As, it can be seen, both variables got replaced. This means that the `replace` method happened inplace. However if I do:

```
self.name = self.laser_comboBox.currentText() #Get name from a qt widget
latex_name = str(self.name).replace("_", r"\_") #Converting to str and then replacing _ for \_
print self.name
print latex_name
```

I'll get:

```
XXXXXX-YY_SN2017060009
XXXXXX-YY\_SN2017060009
```

This is something that puzzled me..I'd like to know why this is happening...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've run some tests here and I think I've found the answer.

My var `self.name` has a `<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>` type, since I'm getting it from a QtWidget. 
Someone, please, correct me if I'm wrong but from the tests I run and from the docs (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace) it seems that the `replace` method in `<class 'PyQt4.QtCore.QString'>` happens inplace. Whereas for the Python `str`, it does not since python strings are immutable.

So, in short:

- Python `str`:  `inplace=False` (Python strings are immutable)
- `PyQt4.QtCore.QString`:  `inplace=True`

Anyway, hope this can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

When you do `self.name` you are actually replacing in place on the objects `name` string.

However when you do `str(self.name)` you are replacing on the new object created by `str` which is not `self.name`. Hence `self.name` remains unchanged.